# Repositories podem manipular e "transformar" dados?

Tags: php, laravel, orientação-a-objetos, ddd

Estou implementando duas APIs de serviços de vídeo (Youtube e Vimeo), e por se tratar de uma camada de dados, achei ideal criar repositórios para cada um, sendo a API a "fonte" dos dados.

algo como:

```
class YoutubeApiRepository implements VideoRepositoryContract
{
    public function search(string $term): ?array
    {
        $YoutubeApi = new YoutubeApi;
        return $YoutubeApi->findVideos('baby shark');
        // return Google_Service_YouTube_SearchResult
    }
}

class VimeoApiRepository implements VideoRepositoryContract
{
    public function search(string $term): ?array
    {
        $VideoApi = new VimeoApiClient;
        return $VideoApi->findAllByTerm('baby shark')
        // return []
    }
}
```

O "problema" é que cada API tem um retorno num formato diferente...

1 - Seria errado um repository iterar e manipular os resultados dessas API para padronizá-los?
ou isso seria melhor se atrubuído à uma outra classe "transformadora"?

2 - No caso de uma classe transformadora, sendo criada uma interface e uma implementação concreta para cada repositório, como
seria possível padronizar os paramêtros passados? por exemplo, o Youtube
retorna uma instância do Objeto `Google_Service_YouTube_SearchResult`, já o Vimeo
retorna um `Array` "cru", e qualquer dado poderia ser passado para o transformador...

Exemplo da classe "transformadora":

```
Interface VideoResponseTransformer
{
    public function transform($rawData): array
}

class YoutubeResponseTransformer implements VideoResponseTransformer
{
    public function transform($rawData) //Google_Service_YouTube_SearchResult
    {
        foreach ($rawData as $video) {
            ....
        }
   }
}

class VimeoResponseTransformer implements VideoResponseTransformer
{
    public function transform($rawData) //Array
    {
        foreach ($rawData as $video) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Curiosidade você está usando em um framework?

Comment: Sim, estou usando Laravel

Comment: Não seria só isso: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#generating-resources que você precisa?

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, sei que existem os resources, mas queria saber como implementar essa solução independente de framework

Comment: olha só isso é problemático: `YoutubeApiRepository implements VideoRepositoryContract` e `class VimeoApiRepository implements VideoRepositoryContract` o correto é que cada repositorio implemente exclusivamente sua Interface, até pode extender dessa mas, cada uma tem a sua principalmente para trabalhar com injeção de dependencia. A outra parte de formatar os dados segue o exemplo que citei e se consegue ler esses dados pode formatar a sua maneira você está no caminho mas, falta algumas alterações no seu código.

Comment: Entendi, só que dessa forma, com interfaces diferentes, essas duas classes não seriam facilmente substituíveis, certo?

Comment: Como assim? não entendi!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu gostaria de que essas implementações pudessem ser substituídas de forma simples, e sendo do mesmo tipo (mesma interface), eu consigo isso

Comment: Thiago não !!! você ai está quebrando a responsabilidade única, em POO é dito que cada código resolve um problema, e você está condensando tudo em um, é o que eu disse cada Classe concreta tem a sua interface e essa interface pode extender de outra interface tipo padrão, porque na hora da Injeção você vai especificar a classe que implementa a concreta. Bom é assim que eu monto e que vejo fazer, inclusive o próprio Framework Laravel é assim.

Comment: basicamente: `interface VideoRepositoryContract extends RepositoryContract` e `class YoutubeApiRepository implements VideoRepositoryContract` e assim por diante, sendo que `RepositoryContract` é sua base principal.

Comment: Ah uma coisa que eu vi esses dias no seu código: `$YoutubeApi = new YoutubeApi;` e `$VideoApi = new VimeoApiClient;` poderia ser injetado também e essas duas classes serem projetadas da mesma forma. Bom é uma idéia de como utilizar.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic mas como isso está infrigindo a responsabilidade única? o repository só retorna os dados, e a dúvida é se eles também podem manipular eles, e no Laravel eu não uso a classe concreta, o parâmetro passado é o da Interface, e o service container do Laravel consegue montar uma classe concreta depois

Comment: Então, eu não acho que faz muito sentido ter uma interface genérica de repositório, pois cada tipo tem suas características (interfaces diferentes), o que você acha?

Answer (score 3):

> 1 - Seria errado um repository iterar e manipular os resultados dessas
> API para padronizá-los? ou isso seria melhor se atrubuído à uma outra
> classe "transformadora"?

Por que isso seria errado? Seu pensamento inicial está correto, você criou uma interface que abstrai a comunicação com os diversos serviços de vídeo que você vai consumir. Você tratou esses serviços como repositório, e não há problema algum nisso, mas seu objetivo principal nessa abordagem é **abstrair o acesso aos diversos serviços de vídeo que existem por aí**.

A partir daí você pode criar uma Factory para conseguir a implementação correta de acordo com o tipo de serviço que você irá consumir. Você também pode adicionar suporte a outros serviços a qualquer momento sem a necessidade de alterar algo nos serviços já existentes.

> 2 - No caso de uma classe transformadora, sendo criada uma interface e
> uma implementação concreta para cada repositório, como seria possível
> padronizar os paramêtros passados? por exemplo, o Youtube retorna uma
> instância do Objeto Google_Service_YouTube_SearchResult, já o Vimeo
> retorna um Array "cru", e qualquer dado poderia ser passado para o
> transformador...

Acho que você já deu a resposta nesse ponto. Cada plataforma irá tratar os dados de forma diferente, isso é um detalhe de implementação e não de utilização, e por este motivo você não precisa criar uma interface para tentar unificar isso. A menos que você consiga encontrar um padrão para construir sua interface, e se isso não for muito custoso pra você, eu sugiro que você trate a transformação do dado como uma responsabilidade da implementação de cada repositório.

Sobre o comentário do @Virgilio, se você deseja realizar uma injeção de dependência por construtor será necessário que suas classes implementem uma interface específica para cada um. Você teria um `IYoutubeRepository` e um `IVimeoRepository` por exemplo, mas pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, sua ideia é realmente poder substituir e desacoplar as implementações de diferentes plataformas.

Se este for o caso, você pode usar uma interface de factory como `IVideoRepositoryFactory` que pode receber a plataforma (viemo, youtube, etc.) como parâmetro e te retornar uma instância correta de `IVideoRepositoryContract`. Se você decidir seguir por este caminho, a injeção de dependência deixaria de ser especificamente da plataforma, e você passaria a injetar a própria Factory. Vai depender da sua implementação e necessidade.

> só fiquei em dúvida qual seria a vantagem real da factory, já que ela
> teria que retornar um repository também, pode criar um exemplo?

Factory é um padrão que resolve problemas para criar objetos. Ele não entra em conflito com o padrão de Dependency Inversion, cujo objetivo principal é diminuir o acoplamento entre os componentes do seu sistema. Eles resolvem problemas diferentes e podem ser utilizados em conjunto, e o seu caso é um bom exemplo disso. Você tem um serviço que procura por videos, que pode ter diversas implementações de acordo com cada plataforma. Quem vai consumir este serviço não precisa se preocupar em encontrar qual é a implementação correta para a plataforma que ele está procurando, e para resolver este problema você pode utilizar uma fábrica. Segue abaixo um pseudo-código sobre isso e um [link do stack exchange  software engineering com uma discussão semelhante.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220640/factory-pattern-and-or-dependency-injection)

```
class Video { }

interface IVideoFinder{
    Video search(string url);
}

// várias implementações YoutubeFinder, VimeoFinder, DailyMotionFinder...

interface IVideoFactory {
    VideoFinder create(string url);
}

class VideoFactory : IVideoFactory {
    VideoFinder create(string url) {
    // Retorna o VideoFinder correto de acordo com a URL da plataforma
    }
}

class Consumer{
    Consumer(IVideoFactory videoFactory) { }
    DoSomething(string url) {
        var video = videoFactory.create(url).search(url)
        // Fazer algo com as informações de video, independente da plataforma...
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, só fiquei em dúvida qual seria a vantagem real da factory, já que ela teria que retornar um repository também, pode criar um exemplo? obrigado!

Comment: Com a Fabrica (ou `Factory`) que é a funcionalidade é criação de instância, quebraria DI e IOC dele, mas, você poderia exemplificar em código sem implementação a sua resposta, fiquei curioso, até nem respondi porque ultimamente levo votos negativos sem merecer principalmente por perguntas assim. Gostei da sua resposta só não entendi se esse é o caso dele por causa do Framework que ele mesmo está utilizando.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic utilizar uma Factory é uma das formas de conseguir uma instância de uma estrutura em tempo de execução, e não quebra o DI. Também seria possível utilizar o próprio container de dependência, dependendo do framework eles oferecem um Service Locator, mas é bem mais difícil de entender o código uma vez que o Service Locator não é contextualizado. Acredito que isso é tema para uma outra pergunta, essa já está bem grande.

Comment: @Vinícius no Laravel que é framework em questão o Factory não seria o ideal. mas, ai cada um pensa na sua estratégia de desenvolvimento, e pelo que ele postou não tem como dizer nada.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic por que o factory não seria o Ideal? acho que isso independe de framework, até por isso que eu deixei sem a tag do Laravel, mas alguém adicionou

Comment: @ThiagoDias se não colocou dados importantes para responder sua pergunta, omitiu o fato do framework e no que está na pergunta não é ideal, eu não usaria um classe só para criar instância porque é legal tem que ter um objetivo claro que denote usar um código assim, porque não fazer o simples? porque complicar? você está usando `interface` e isso denota implementação dela, eu não preciso então de um `Fabric` agora tudo depende para que e quando usar tal padrão. Enfim a resposta do amigo está certa, mas, porque ele mesmo relatou falta mais contexto, por isso eu nem respondi.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Porque o framework não é importante nesse caso, esse trecho de código facilmente poderia ser do Symfony, que também possui o Service Container.
Me desculpe, mas eu não entendi o que você quis dizer não usar uma interface, é só olhar a assinatura dela

Comment: @ThiagoDias eu não disse para não usar `interface` eu disse usar um o outro, eu sei que o código do Framework Laravel sua base é Symfony eu venho desde os primordios desse Framework quando era tudo `Facade`, então eu estou dizendo que você pode usar `interface` e classes que implementam (concreta), mas, que isso seja implementada com responsabilidade unica, mas, precisa sim escrever um código exemplo para você entender todo o processo e na sua pergunta não tem o modelo de retorno das APIs. Observer que isso aqui no site é um faz para mim e a gente só leva voto negativos fazendo isso.